# Finding $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2r+5}{r^2+r}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> $\text{Find the value of}$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2r+5}{r^2+r}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r+1}\right)$$
>
> $\text{Answer}: \frac{9}{5}$

Firstly I split "linear-upon-quadratic" term:
$$\frac{2r+5}{r^2+r}=\frac{5}{r}-\frac{3}{r+1}
\\ =\frac{2}{r}+3\left(\frac {1}{r} -\frac {1}{r+1}\right)$$
If it hadn't been for the $\left(\frac 35\right)^{r+1}$ term, the above step would have been very useful - splitting the single summation into two and summing individually.

Unfortunately, that's not the case. I'm unable to proceed further, though my gut says telescoping is the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea was right:$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{r}-\frac{3}{r+1}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r+1}$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{r}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r+1}-\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{r+1}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r+1}$$
$$=3\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r}-3\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{r}$$
$$
=3\cdot \underbrace{\frac{3}{5}}_{r=1}=\frac{9}{5}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- $$\int\sum=\sum\int$$
- $$\int x^rdx=\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$$
- $$\int x^{r-1}dx=\frac{x^{r}}{r}$$
- $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} x^r=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: I appreciate your help, but thing is, this question was from the chapter of Limits and we hadn't been taught Integration by then. Also, $$\int \sum=\sum\int$$ isn't in our syllabus.

Comment: No problem. The other solution is more elegant anyway.